# Numpy alternatives for linear algebra and kinematics in python?

Tags: kinematics, python

Are there any decent python numerical package libraries besides numpy for python? Numpy relies on gfortan which itself must be compiled correctly for your platform to avoid hidden/insidious numerical errors in numpy.

I need a matrix algebra package to do kinematics, path planning, and machine learning in python that isn't sensitive to  `gfortran` version and compiler options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/refman.html) is available with python bindings. It's not geared at strictly numerical applications, but it might be sufficient.

It includes some [matrix math](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) and [machine learning](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/ml.html) algorithms.

I can't say you won't ever experience numerical problems, but it's not based on gfortran.

Comment: Awesome. just what I was looking for. And it kills a flock of birds with one stone.